# Safari delete my localstorage data by itself

Tags: javascript, rest, safari, local-storage

I'm using localstorage for save "key": "value".
Safari is saving it, but after request, for example axios.get (..., {Authorization: "value"}, what is going on immediately, Safari just delete my "key":"value" from localstorage.
How I can fix it? Can't find an answer for it anywhere

Comment: If you could post an example that would be great. Your actual code would be ideal. And possibly some screen shots

Answer (score 0):

I misread the situation.
If anyone have the same issue, when after request safari delete your localstorage data which you used - check requests string.

I had:
localstorage with:

```
"valueToken" : "Bearer token..."
```

`http://someapiroute.com/${param}`, with `{Authorization: ${valueToken}}`
And Safari make redirect by itself to `http://someapiroute.com/${param}**/**` and with it safari lose your params, and eventually delete your data from localstorage

Solution:
Add `/` into the end of your request string by yourself, for example: `http://someapiroute.com/${param}/` instead of `http://someapiroute.com/${param}`